# Loop not showing up on page template

Tags: loop, page-template

I have a page template and on the page I have a loop such as:

```
query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); 
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

The problem is that no posts are coming back when there should be about 5 or 6. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use `WP_query` instead of `query_posts`:

Secondly, for (static) pages use the variable 'page' (not 'paged').

```
$my_query = new WP_query( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&paged='  .get_query_var('page') );
if ( $my_query->have_posts() )  while( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

Comment: That still didnt work, also: $my_query->the_title() is wrong. you only use $my_query up until the_post(). everything after like content, title, thumbnail and so on does not need it. - UPDate: it works

Comment: I'm glad it helped. And sorry for the wrong title referencing. I guess, I was too busy doing copy/paste of `$my_query->`. ;)